# How to declare a local constant in C#?

Tags: c#, immutability, readonly, local-variables

How to declare a local constant in C# ?

Like in Java, you can do the following :

```
public void f(){
  final int n = getNum(); // n declared constant
}
```

How to do the same in C# ? I tried with `readonly` and `const` but none seems to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This is the most annoying omission from C# in my short time using it.  I use const on local variables in C++ all the time for my own safety, sanity, and readability.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/443687/why-does-c-sharp-disallow-readonly-local-variables

Comment: @MauricioScheffer, thanks for the link. Though now if I have to write something for .NET, I'll most certainly be using F#. :-)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In C#, you cannot create a constant that is retrieved from a method.

Edit: dead link
<strike>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b(VS.71).aspx</strike>

This doc should help:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/const

> A constant expression is an expression that can be fully evaluated at
>   compile time.

Comment: Well, that sucks. :/

Comment: Brutal. I should not only be supported, it should be the default.

Comment: `final` and `const` have different meanings.  In C#, a `const` value must be known at compile time.  The real issue is that C# does not support local `readonly` variables, which is too bad because they'd be handy.

Comment: @Nick, in c++ it is not necessary that local const must be known at compile time.

Comment: While const in C# must be assigned constant values known at compile time (or evaluate-able at compile time), there's no reason why at runtime, something like readonly for properties, could also be applied to locals, am I wrong? AFAIK, readonly is enforced at runtime in C# for properties (even though it's an error at compile time as well). We could have local `var readonly id = GetId();` for example. Even `var const id = -1;`, which is basically a literal that becomes substituted by its value.

Comment: not sure why this is the accepted answer. for me, the answer from @TamasCzinege looks well-explained and helpful. should check the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2054775/9195902.

Answer (score 23):

Declare your local variable as an iteration variable. Iteration variables are readonly
(You didn't ask for a pretty solution).

```
public void f() 
{
  foreach (int n in new int[] { getNum() }) // n declared constant
  {
    n = 3; // won't compile: "error CS1656: Cannot assign to 'n' because it is a 'foreach iteration variable'"
  }
}
```

Comment: Good to know, but god promise, not gonna do that ever.

Comment: That's golden) This hack is so ugly I didn't even think about it. I will definitely use it (as a snippet) to check my code, you know, temporary changing `var index=GetNum()` to `foreach` to force the compiler to check my code.

Comment: omg. Still banging my head on the table as I am serisouly considering using this hack. What a truly dirty one ;-)

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure why `readonly` and `const` didn't work for you since these are the keywords you need. You use `const` if you have a literal (except for array literals) and `readonly` otherwise:

```
public void f()
{
    const int answer = 42;
}

private readonly int[] array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
private readonly DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
public void g()
{
    Console.WriteLine(date.ToString());   
}
```

`readonly` only works on class level (that is, you can only apply it to fields). Also as a consequence of `const` requiring a literal, it's inherently static while a `readonly` field can be either static or instance.

Comment: It's important to note that creating a readonly instance of a reference type only means that the reference itself can't be changed; the object can still be modified normally (unless the type is immutable, like String).

Comment: The answer to **your** question is simple -- none of them (const, readonly) would work in a given example.

Answer (score 6):

As of 2018-10-02, it isn't possible to have a readonly local in c#, but there is an open [proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/readonly_locals.md) for that feature that has ongoing [discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/188).

This [article](https://www.infoq.com/news/2017/04/CSharp-Readonly-Locals) provides a useful summary.

Answer (score 4):

There is a sort of workaround that requires ReSharper. You can't get readonly locals, but you can at least detect mutated ones and color them differently.

Use the Fonts and Colors item **Resharper Mutable Local Variable Identifier**.

For me, I have locals colored grey, and then I chose a bold white for the mutated variables (this is with a dark theme). This means that any variable that is written to more than once shows up bright compared to regular ones. You can then do what you can to try to avoid having a mutated variable, or if the method really does require one then it will at least be highlighted.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. It only shows the loop counters as unmutable, everything else is mutable, no matter how many writes. I guess my Resharper is too old :-)

Comment: @Xan-KunClark-Davis it doesn't show what is mutable, it shows what is mutated. anything that is written to exactly once will look normal. anything that is written to twice or more will be highlighted. (oh I guess you said "no matter how many writes"). are you sure? something like `int x = 5; x = 3;`, x should change color. I guess it could be the version, yeah.

Comment: @ Sahuagin Yeah, I get the part that you kinda have to invert it, all locals get highlightet and all mutables get "normaled" again, but still, it doesn't change the color. I will try with a clean project again.

Comment: Ok, I opened a new workspace and tried it again, and it works! Real magic :-) The only thing is, there is one behaviour I do not understand but it would be too complicated to explain here.

Comment: OMG! I really love it now :-)

Answer (score 1):

In the example you gave, you need to declare the variable as `static`, because you're initializing it with a method call.  If you were initializing with a constant value, like 42, you can use `const`.  For classes, structs and arrays, `readonly` should work.

Comment: Please note that you cannot use static on variables, only on members.

Answer (score 0):

> The const keyword is used to modify a
>   declaration of a field or local
>   variable.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b%28VS.71%29.aspx).

Since C# can't enforce "const correctnes" (like c++) anyway, I don't think it's very useful. Since functions are very narrwoly scoped, it is easy not to lose oversight.

Comment: I must point out however, that eric dahlvang is still right about why const didn't work in your case.

Comment: "Since functions are very narrwoly scoped, it is easy not to lose oversight." - Why do other languages like C++ and Java provide such mechanism then?

Comment: Don't know about java, but c++ can enforce true const also on references, what c# can't. I have never seen const used locally anywhere else than in c++.

Comment: _“Since functions are very narrwoly scoped, it is easy not to lose oversight.”_ — Not true. Using constants as much as possible is actually a main trait of functional programming.  — _“I have never seen const used locally anywhere else than in c++”_ — When I was programming C++ I was using `const` all the the time. On parameter, return values, local variables. Everything what could be declared const i declared const.

Comment: I cannot agree with the statement that it's not useful. In fact, it's super useful. If I see a local const variable I immediately know that I won't be surprised later. It does wonders for readability.