# Immutable local 'variables' in C#

Tags: c#, immutability

I'm new to C# (C++ programmer mainly, with Java as a strong second, and some others I use less often); I'm using C# with Unity, but I have a question that seems to be C# related rather than Unity.

I've been moving somewhat towards functional-style programming, i.e. instead of

```
// C++
int someFunction(int a) {
    int someCalculatedValue = a * a;
    someCalculatedValue /= 2;
    return someCalculatedValue * 3;
}
```

I'd do something like this

```
// Again C++
int someFunction(int a) {
    const int inputSquared = a * a;
    const int inputSquaredHalved = inputSquared / 2;
    return inputSquaredHalved * 3;
}
```

Now, I'd like to do that in C#, but I've tried this

```
// C#
const float maxGrowth = GrowthRate * Time.deltaTime;
```

But Mono complains, saying maxGrowth isn't being assigned a 'constant value' - so I'm assuming C#'s const keyword is actually equivalent to 'constexpr' from C++11?

If so, is there a way of doing what I want in C#? Preferably without invoking some container class (unless the compiler is good at making that efficient?).

I assume from what I've read C# is much closer to Java overall than C++ in language; immutable classes rather than const-member functions?

Comment: Your title talks about immutable _local_ variables, yet your question only mentions "something like this" (is that C++?) and "what I want" (what?). Can you explain what you want this code, or `const` specifically, to do? Did you read [How to declare a local constant in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054761/how-to-declare-a-local-constant-in-c) and [What does immutable and readonly mean in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849114/what-does-immutable-and-readonly-mean-in-c)?

Comment: 'a question that seems to be C# related rather than C#.' Doug can you clear this up?

Comment: Almost all of c#'s primitive types are mutable in the sense they behave like a mutable container for a value. I would really suggest you to take a look at the better and more functional C#s brother - F#

Comment: If you want to, you could use anonymous types. `var inputSquared = new { Value = a * a }; var inputSquaredHalved = new { Value = inputSquared.Value / 2 }; return inputSquaredHalved.Value * 3;` Kinda sucks syntax wise, and pushes it to an object with a readonly field. No idea how this might JIT in terms of optimization or performance.

Comment: Apologies all, I've editted to clear up a mistake and make it clear the examples where in C++ rather than C#

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: Thanks for the tip, didn't know C# has anonymous types; still very early learning in terms of the jump between C++11 and C#, heh.

Comment: Since you're going the functional route, you could also wrap these as methods: `Func<int> inputSquared = () => a * a; Func<int> inputHalved = () => inputSquared() / 2; return inputSquaredHalved() / 3;` But this just kinda puts more overhead on the closure patterns being used (though this can be offset by ditching the closure entirely for a input variables on the functions) EDIT: And again, your mileage may vary in terms of performance and compiler/JIT optimizations (which in itself may differ from platform to platform)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Not sure how those options really save you, the local variable `inputSquared` is still assignable either way. You would just have to create a new instance of the same anonymous type or delegate.

Comment: @Doug http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/why-use-fsharp/

Comment: @mikez: Hah, yeah, fair enough. In the end, there really is no analogue in C# (But they are tending to add more immutability, so maybe cross your fingers for C#7?). I should clarify: my comments are just for conceptual discussion (or for laughs); I wouldn't really be in favour of using either of them. In a C# mindset, you'll probably be best off simply having tiny pure methods.

Comment: C# should bring in the ``let`` keyword as an alternative to ``var`` as other languages have (Swift, F#, JabbaScript).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**There is no equivalent for local variables: Declare it as a field.**

### [`readonly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx)

When a field declaration includes a readonly modifier, assignments to the fields introduced by the declaration can only occur as part of the declaration or in a constructor in the same class.

Comment: Was that last sentence there right from the start? I could have sworn I did read it all before, but apologies if not. I don't think guidance of "make it a field" is applicable though - look at the example, where the value depends on the parameter. Unless you're suggesting turning the method call into its own class, this isn't an alternative.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Well, I don't call that a constant.  I suppose we could create some special type that does that, but what for?  If the method is complicated enough to need local immutability, it probably deserves its own class anyway.

Comment: I had read about readonly, but was surprised to see it wasn't applicable to local variables (abit odd really). Sad to see that the 'readonly locals' aren't available in C#, they have been useful in preventing some nonsense mistakes. Oh well.

Comment: The OP didn't call it a constant either :) But making it clear which local variables may change and which may not is a definite style from some functional languages (e.g. F# too). I think that "no, you just can't do that in C#" is probably more appropriate than referring to `readonly`, personally.

Comment: @Doug: `readonly` assumes the presence of a constructor that sets the initial value of the field.  Methods don't have constructors.

Answer (score 25):

You can declare your local variable as an iteration variable. Iteration variables are readonly.
Yes, it is ugly.

```
foreach (float maxGrowth in new[] { GrowthRate * Time.deltaTime })
{
  maxGrowth = 0; // won't compile: "error CS1656: Cannot assign to 'maxGrowth' because it is a 'foreach iteration variable'"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that a better way for this case is using statement

Sample:

```
using (var font = new Font("Arial", 10.0f)) 
{
    byte charset = font.GdiCharSet;
}
```

font variable is immutable

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement

Comment: `float` does not implement `IDisposable`, i don't see how this answer the question.

Comment: I understand that this question is not only about the primitive types, but I respect your comment, I think about this too

Comment: Since this question is obviously for people learning C#, this response is valuable. Thus voted up.

Comment: Hi, this does work, however, it's just a syntax sugar for the foreach loop. Basically, `using` statements [get compiled down to foreach loops](https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/functional-csharp-immutability-anonymous-type-and-tuple)