# The Expression assigned to X must be constant?

Tags: c#, string, constants

I got that error with this code:

```
const string body = HighPoint; // HighPoint is a string arg passed in to the method
```

...and was able to work around it by removing the constant:

```
string body = HighPoint;
```

...or, of course, assigning a constant value:

```
const string body = "My Dinner with Andre";
```

...but is "my way not a very sporting way"? (gratuitous *Princess Bride* reference)

Comment: Basically you are looking for a readonly local, and that is not a feature that C# supports.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/443687/why-does-c-sharp-disallow-readonly-local-variables

Comment: I guess what's strange to me is that somebody would make something like this const in the first place. I derived this code from a sample on sending email. When would you ever have the same exact body in an email (unless you were a spammer maybe)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The keyword `const` in C# means a compile-time constant. It is different from C++ and C, where the same keyword requires only a run-time const-ness.

Answer (score 5):

`const` in C# is different from `const` in C++.

In C++, `const` a runtime constant. The following operations are valid in C++

i.e

```
const char *CONST_INFO = "hello world";
CONST_INFO = "goodbye world"; //aok
const int i = SomeMethod(); //aok
```

C#, on the other hand, is stricter. The constant value must be constant at compile time; no method returns or static class members.

If you need to use a one-off value as a constant (i.e an array, or a method return) you can use the static and readonly modifiers to emulate most of the restrictions the `const` keyword gives you:

```
public static readonly string body = HighPoint;
```

Should compile fine, and you'll still exprience similar restrictions with modifying the value as you would with `const`