# Unable to apply readonly keyword on method scope but const is working fine

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Why we can not apply readonly key word on method scope.but const is working fine.

```
public void show(){
   const string test = "test";      
}
public void show(){
   readonly string test="test";
}
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Oh I see. I pointed out that your question doesn't make sense and you changed the question. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

`readonly` cannot be used in that context. It can only be used when declaring fields inside class/struct.

> The **`readonly`** keyword is a modifier that you can use on fields.

> You use the **`const`** keyword to declare a constant field or a constant local.

Therefore your code doesn't even compile and doesn't make sense. To see difference between `readonly` and `const` when declaring fields see [What is the difference between const and readonly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55984/what-is-the-difference-between-const-and-readonly).

**Update**

To see why C# does not allow `readonly` local variables see [Why does C# disallow readonly local variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443687/why-does-c-sharp-disallow-readonly-local-variables)